# PayPal API Class not found error on hosted server

Tags: php, class, paypal, namespaces

I'm really having some difficulty with a e-commerce site I've created using PayPal's REST API to process payments.

I set all this up and it was working great in my server environment (using XAMPP running PHP 7.1.1) but i have recently moved the project to a hosted server (1and1 running PHP 7.0) and now I'm receiving the following error (I've made a test script showing the same error as my checkout.php to save unnecessary code):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PayPal\API\payer' not found in /homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/test.php on line 6

test.php:

```
<?php
require __DIR__."/bootstrap.php";

use PayPal\API\payer;

$test = new payer();
?>
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
// Used for composer based installation
// require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use below for direct download installation
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

define('SITE_URL', 'http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/paypal');

// sandbox credentials
$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',     // ClientID
            'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'      // ClientSecret
        )
);
?>
```

autoload.php

```
<?php
    // autoload.php @generated by Composer

    require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

    return ComposerAutoloaderInitddf6726757c04c8de8443463a9140734::getLoader();
```

I know that this is due to namespaces/classes and I've lost count of the hours I've spent Googling and scouring Stack Overflow for answers and am now admitting defeat and asking for help. I apologise in advance if there is a duplicate answer, there are many with similar errors, but none I have seen have been able to explain/resolve my specific problem.

What I really can't get my head around is why this works OK on my local server, but not on the hosted server. I know my requires are OK because if I input echo "test"; for example in the relevant .PHP files, then it is outputted to the screen.

I am not using composer or any similar software, everything has been written in notepad++. The Paypal API is unmodified ([from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw91zs6tvwqm4on/PayPal-PHP-SDK.zip?dl=0)) and sits in my root directory as "/PayPal-PHP-SDK/".

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Would you give code of autoload.php and your Paypal class?

Comment: Might be a case issue... did you try `Payer()` instead of `payer()` ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I've tried Payer and Paypal (lowercase P) and various combinations of the two to no avail.

Comment: Shouldn't you be including `vendor/autoload.php`?

Comment: I believe vendor/autoload.php is for Composer based installations, which mine is not, although I may look at using it if I have no success

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Randall,

It was indeed a case issue where the hosted Linux server was fussy about the case and my Windows server was not.

I needed to set Api instead of API in my use statement and Payer (vs payer) as below:

```
<?php
require __DIR__."/bootstrap.php";

use PayPal\Api\Payer;

$test = new Payer();
?>
```